# Excel VBA codes about background fill

Tags: vba, excel, background, fill

I work with MIT Excel tables. I need to copy "cell fill" to "another fill" and I've done this by using this code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("A:A").Copy
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

How can I modify it so that it works between two different sheets?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to avoid using `.Select` and start working with objects. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

So your code can be written as

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    '~~> Change as Applicable
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ws1.Columns("A:A").Copy
    ws2.Columns("B:B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
                                    Operation:=xlNone, _
                                    SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                    Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Further to the discussion in comments, if you want to use the Codenames, then use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    '~~> Change as Applicable
    Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Set ws2 = Sheet2

    ws1.Columns("A:A").Copy
    ws2.Columns("B:B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
                                    Operation:=xlNone, _
                                    SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                    Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I know that i am not really educated in this, but when i write in the code it doesn't work for me, do i have to change something in it, except i changed only sheet numbers to 3 and 4.

Comment: Does Col A have any formatting in the relevant sheet?

Comment: Yes, it has fill colour, which is the main thing i need, some text and other formating. And as i try to run it it says - Run-time error 9, Subscript out of range

Comment: Yes, it has fill colour, which is the main thing i need, some text and other formating.

Comment: Well then the code will work as expected :) Check Col B of the other worksheet. BTW are both the sheets in the same workbook?

Comment: For what should i check in col B?

Comment: Then check the names of the worksheets. You have spelt the name wrong (It may have an extra space in the name?)

Comment: Since this is only a sample Workbook, i have the base names. I am not messing with the real table. And as it seems it doesn' t like smthn. about Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

Comment: Are you sure the name of the worksheet is "Sheet3"? If you want to use code names then change the line `Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")` to `Set ws1 = [Sheet3]` similarly `Set ws2 = [Sheet4]`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Why `[Sheet3]` rather than just `Sheet3`?

Comment: @Rory: No particular reason :) Old habits die hard I guess :)

Comment: @Annija: You can remove the brackets and it will still work :)